# Equivalence class of definite integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let's assume we have a smooth function $f(x):[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ so that the integral $$\int_a^b f(x) dx$$ is finite. By performing various changes of variables, we can derive a large (infinite?) number of different definite integrals which evaluate to the same value as the original integral. We could even introduce the concept of an equivalence class of definite integrals connected by a change of variables. Do such equivalence classes exist? Are they even remotely useful?

Comment: If you restrict to the case where $f(x)$ is a rational function, this is reminiscent of [periods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods), where you allow not only changes of variables, but also additivity (in the integrand and domain of integration) and use of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Do you allow multiplication by real numbers and addition of a real number? Because a lot of transformations lead to that (partial fractions, integration by parts, etc)